# Ignited Datatable with 'if ' query

Tags: codeigniter, datatable

How to put a 'if' query on Ignited datatable? Here is my query:

This is my controller:

```
function ajaxGetCard() {

    $this->load->library('Datatables');
    $this->datatables->set_database('retail');
    $this->datatables
         ->select('studEmpID, fullname, serialNumber, balance, If(status = "0", "Enable", "Disabled") as status')
         ->from('retail_card');

    echo $this->datatables->generate();
}
```

This is my view:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        "bProcessing": true,
        "bserverSide": true,
        "ajax": "<?php echo site_url('card/ajaxGetCard'); ?>",
        "columns": [
            { "data": "studEmpID" },
            { "data": "fullname" },
            { "data": "serialNumber" },
            { "data": "balance" },
            { "data": "status" },
            { "data": "actions" }
          ]
    } );
});
</script>

<table class="table table-bordered datatable table-striped" id="example">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>ID Number</th>
        <th width="30%">Name</th>
        <th>Serial</th>
        <th>Balance (MYR)</th>
        <th>Status</th>
        <td>Actions</td>
    </tr>
</thead>
```

When I run this, I've  got this error:

```
DataTables warning: table id=example - Ajax error. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/7
```

I already refer the given url, but still not solve the problem. If I remove the the 'if' statement in that query, everything works fine. Please help

Comment: What is Ignited in your title did you mean codeIgniter?

Comment: https://github.com/IgnitedDatatables/Ignited-Datatables/